# Speeding up a very slow Vuetify Filter method

Tags: arrays, typescript, filter, vuetify.js

I have a working filter method, however it is very slow. text input is passed into $store, and a function is applied to see if anything in an array is a partial match for the text-input. Essentially I am using a computed function to iterate over to display components.

This is effectively the first thing I've tried. It does work in some capacity, but is unbelievably slow and unoptimized.

```
      <v-flex
        v-for="myFolder in folderFilter"
        :key="myFolder"
        xl2
        md4
        xs6
        justfy-space-around
        style="padding-top:50px;"
      >
        <FolderIcon
          :folderName="myFolder.folderName"
          :folderDescription="myFolder.folderDescription"
          :isReadOnly="myFolder.isReadOnly"
          :addImage="myFolder.addImage"
          :updateHeader="myFolder.updateHeader"
        ></FolderIcon>
      </v-flex>
```

```
  computed: {
    folderFilter(): Folder[] {
      let returnFolder: Folder[] = new Array();
      if (
        this.$store.state.search === "" ||
        this.$store.state.search === null
      ) {
        return this.$store.state.displayArray;
      } else {
        this.$store.state.displayArray.forEach((element: Folder) => {
          if (
            element.folderName
              .toLowerCase()
              .includes(this.$store.state.search.toLowerCase())
          ) {
            returnFolder.push(element);
          }
        });
      }
      return returnFolder;
    }
  },
```

It does work, however when I add more input it is very laggy to take input.

Comment: What, specifically, does this do?  How large is the search space?

Comment: The search space is over a 250~ item array. Consider it something like a file explorer search feature. There is a toolbar that takes input and effectively passes it off to the folderFilter() computed method. The results of folderFilter() are then iterated over to display items.

Comment: I guess it does look up for the entire array whenever you input a new character ? If it's the case, you could try to tweak it a bit to reduce the array to lookup everytime you input a new character.
i.e. I have an array `[ab, ac, ad, ae, be]`. If I start typing `"a"`, the search array only contains `[ab, ac, ad, ae]` so your next character lookup will only loop over 4 items instead of 5. In this way, the more characters you input, the faster it looks up.

Comment: Thats likely what the issue is related to. Yes I do want the entire array looped over when I add another character, however I can probably do something about later characters not searching over the whole array, but like you said, a reduced version of it.

Comment: You can also make your search method asynchronized. Make an async lookup method, then call it on a `@change` event on the text input. That way it won't block your input while the lookup is ongoing. Sorry I don't have enough time to write any answer code, I hope this helps you a bit at least.

Comment: No trouble whatsoever. Both of these are good ideas and worth trying. No example code needed, the ideas in both situations make a great deal of sense and are easily implemented.